# error: index out of range when retriveing data from firebase snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

im having normal firebase fetching data method but after appending data and calling the function out of the snapshot function my app crashes but when its inside the snapshot function the process becomes successful heres my code:

```
var randumUserKey: String = ""
var counterKey: Int = 0
var counter = 0
var keys = [String]()


Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for a in ((snapshot.value as AnyObject).allKeys)!{
                self.keys.append(a as! String)
              //  self.keys2.append(a as! Int)
               // print(a)
            }
            print("KKEeeys")
            print(self.keys)

        })
        func generateNum(){

                self.randumUserKey = self.keys[self.counter] //this is the error highlighted in red color in xCode
                self.counter += 1

                if self.counter == self.keys.count{
                    self.counter = 0
                    print("counter == 0 now!")
                }

               print("the number is \(self.counter)")
            }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you have any keys?

Comment: my app crashes when using the function "generateNum()" outside the snapshot method

Comment: sorry i forgot to include my keys variable. i edit it and now is there above

Comment: Consider that `observe` works asynchronously. The closure is executed later as a callback. That's the reason why `generateNum` works only within the closure

Comment: but once the closure is running my data already appended in my array so im trying to perform the function with array that been saved

Comment: so is there any way to use array after appending from the snapshot closure ? please advice if any you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebase function is an asyncronized function. That is, when you call `Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe()` method, you are sending a request to firebase server requesting for data in background and then if you call `generateNum()` right after the server call, your keys will not have anything in it. A server request is way slower than running the next line of code.

So you should be using it in this way

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for a in ((snapshot.value as AnyObject).allKeys)!{
        self.keys.append(a as! String)
        print (a + " added")
    }
    self.generateNum()
})
```

Comment: after applying your answer I got this error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException .... what does it mean ?

Comment: also this one: InvalidPathValidation reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @OTAMD Which line does this error coming from, can you post your code please?

Comment: please view my full code here: (go to ActivityViewController.swift) https://github.com/OthmanAmoudi/TinderClone

Comment: @OTAMD That error comes from a misuse of firebase calls. Basically, something is wrong when you call `.child("post")` I am not sure what goes wrong there or what's the format of the path but the problem in this question is already solved. For your firebase path problem, please post a new question.